# Outlook does not recognize one or more names. From 1 computer

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to send an email with several recipients.  On most machines, the program works as expected, but on one I get the following error. ***System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Outlook does not recognize one or more names.***

I have narrowed down what address the machine thinks is the issue and there is nothing wrong with it.

I have tried using using both the recipients and To fields as follows:

```
Outlook.MailItem outLookMsg = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

Outlook.Recipients recips = outLookMsg.Recipients;
Outlook.Recipient recip = recips.Add("'doesntWork@test.com'");
recip.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
outLookMsg.Send()
```

As well as

```
Outlook.MailItem outLookMsg = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
outLookMsg.To = "'doesntWork@test.com'";
outLookMsg.Send()
```

I have tried forcing the program to use the literal email address without resolving by using **'doesntwork@test.com'** with and without the single quotes, but that does not work. I really don't want outlook to try and resolve the recipient, I just want it to send the email.  Anyone run into this before?

Comment: Do you actually pass an SMTP address? What happens on that machine if you create a new message and paste the problematic value in the To editbox and hit Ctrl+K?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I am not passing the SMTP address, I am using the connection through the account in Outlook.  On the problem machine if I type the email address as it is being sent and press ctrl+K is resolves and can be sent the way it should. Eg 'doesntwork@test.com' -> 'doesntwork@test.com' <'doesntwork@test.com'>

Comment: You are passing " the connection through the account in Outlook" to Recipients.Add?!

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Sorry I thought you meant I am connecting to a specific SMTP server address.  Yes I am sending using a SMTP address in both the Recipients.Add and the To:  The addresses are hard coded like the code above only with real addresses.

Comment: Do not use quotes. Also make sure there are no spaces or other characters invalid in SMTP addresses.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have tried without the quotes and have ensured that there are not spaces or invalid characters.  Same result.

Comment: Are you sure you get the same error (Outlook does not recognize one or more names) in both cases (quotes and no quotes) rather than an ambiguous name error? Is there a contact with that address in one of the Contacts folders?